# Tensorflowjs - Reshape/slice 4d tensor into image

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow.js

I am trying to apply style transfer to a webcam capture. I am reading a frozen model I've previously trained in python and converted for TFjs. The output tensor's shape and rank is as follows:
[image]

I am having issues in the last line of this function, when I try to apply tf.browser.toPixels

```
    function predictWebcam() {
  tf.tidy(() => {
    loadmodel().then(model=>{    
      //let tensor= model.predict(tf.expandDims(tf.browser.fromPixels(video))); 
      let tensor= model.predict(tf.browser.fromPixels(video, 3).toFloat().div(tf.scalar(255)).expandDims()); 
      console.log('shape', tensor.shape);
      console.log('rank', tensor.rank);
      tf.browser.toPixels(tensor, resultImage);
    });
  });
}
```

I get this error. I cannot figure out how to reshape or modify the tensor to get an image out of it:

Uncaught (in promise) Error: toPixels only supports rank 2 or 3 tensors, got rank 4.
Maybe I have to replicate tensor_to_image function from python to javascript as in [the example in the website](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/style_transfer).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

given your tensor is `[1, 15, 20, 512]`
you can remove any dims with value of 1 (same dim you've added by running `expandDims`) by running

```
const squeezed = tf.squeeze(tensor)
```

that will give you **shape** of `[15, 20, 512]`

but that still doesn't make sense - what is `width`, `height` and `channels` (e.g. rgb) here?

i think that model result needs additional post-processing, that is not an image.

Comment: Think I have to translate this python function into js:
def tensor_to_image(tensor):
  tensor = tensor*255
  tensor = np.array(tensor, dtype=np.uint8)
  if np.ndim(tensor)>3:
    assert tensor.shape[0] == 1
    tensor = tensor[0]
  return PIL.Image.fromarray(tensor)

I am following this documentation: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/style_transfer#fast_style_transfer_using_tf-hub

Comment: first part is easy: `tf.squeeze(tensor).mul(255).cast('int32')`, but i have no idea what `PIL.image.fromArray()` does - its an external function, not part of TF.

Comment: Think what's left is to translate into js the if condition. Tried with dataSync() but failed to create the image. 
  if np.ndim(tensor)>3:
    assert tensor.shape[0] == 1
    tensor = tensor[0]

Comment: thats all covered in what i wrote, but that tensor does not look like image.